# Eloquent many-to-many relationship and using pivot table as separate model

Tags: php, laravel

While building a laravel web application I faced and interesting problem and I believe there should be a best practice to solve this kind of problem without re-inventing the wheel.

Basically, I have many-to-many relationship:

Post has many categories but at the same time categories can have many posts as well.
Each category that belongs to the post can have "votes". These votes do not belong generally to the category but only to the category_post pivot table entry.

My question is:
Should I create a separate model "CategoryPost" and then use one to many relationship with "votes" table of there is a more elegant way to implement it.

I am also trying to make the querying process as expressive as possible.

Comment: Are you talking about an additional column in pivot table ? If that, then yes it's possible to do so without a new model. Here you'll find details. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Not really. I need to establish one to many relationship with pivot table. Pivot table has ID, post_id and category_id fields and there is another table votes and basically I need user to be able to add votes to the ID of pivot table. Sorry if it is not explained very well. Structure is little tricky because these votes belong to the id of the pivot table and when displaying the post I need to retrieve the number of likes (number of rows in likes table where the pivot_id == pivot_table.id)

Comment: Oh! Got it now. I would go for `CategoryPost` model with one to many relationship with `votes` table then as you mentioned. Nothing elegant other than that is coming around mind right now at this moment. Let's wait for others suggestion.

Comment: Yep, thanks man! I have just  coded it in not the most elegant way but I thought there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wrote such code in category class:

```
public function votes()
{
    // find id of pivot table column
    $categoryPost = CategoryPost::where('skill_id', $this->id)->first();
    if($categoryPost) {

       $likes = Like::where('likeable_id', $categoryPost->id)->get();

        if(count($likes)) {
            return count($likes);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and at the same time I have added class CategoryPost. Now the most elegant solution probably but if there will be a better suggestion it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> From Laravel Documentation about [Eloquent Relationships L 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships):
>
> **Counting Relationship Results**
>
> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will
>   place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models.

For example:

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

You may add retrieve the "counts" for multiple relations as well as add constraints to the queries:

```
$posts = Post::withCount(['votes', 'comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
}])->get();

echo $posts[0]->votes_count;
echo $posts[0]->comments_count;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but that is not what I am looking for actually. My case is  different.